# how to remove p tags within a div?

Tags: jquery

I have a div which contains a paragraph tag which contains text.
What I want is to remove the p tags but keep the text in the div? is this possible in jQuery?

```
<div id="footright"><p>Circus</p></div>
```

Comment: Manipulating the DOM with jQuery? Yes, it *might* be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

```
$('#footright').text($('#footright').text());
```

Answer (score 10):

There's lots of ways you can do it.  I'd probably go with:

```
​$('#footright > p').contents().unwrap();​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#footright>p" ).replaceWith(function() { return $(this).contents(); });
```

Answer (score -2):

You can go with:

```
$('#footright > p').html("");
```